# Spring Boot and Eureka: ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:8761 timed out

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

After changing the Eureka port number from default port to custom port, when running the Eureka client it is showing following error:

```
 Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:8761 timed out
            at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:180) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:134) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:610) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:445) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:835) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:118) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56) ~[httpclient-4.5.6.jar:4.5.6]
            at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
        
    eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
    eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

This is **application.properties** file content:

```ini
    # serivce name
    spring.application.name=student-service
    # port
    server.port=6161
    # eureka server url
    eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:6969/eureka
    eureka.client.registerWithEureka=true
    eureka.client.fetchRegistry=true
```

it is showing

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to localhost:8761
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change configuration for the Eureka registry server `eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone` like following (YAML syntax):

```yaml
eureka:
    client:
        #registerWithEureka: false
        #fetchRegistry: false
        serviceUrl:
            defaultZone: http://${eureka.instance.hostname}:${server.port}/eureka/
```